# how to compare a string to a an expression has an ampersand in it

Tags: c#, asp.net

I'm trying to compare a string to another string that has an ampersand in it.

```
if (CategoryType.ToUpper() == "E&D")
```

when I compare these 2 strings it displays as `E&amp;D`. How can I do the comparison?

Comment: How would comparing two strings display something? Could you describe that more accurately?

Comment: You could use `HttpUtility.HtmlDecode(CategoryType).ToUpper()` to get it back to `"E&D"`

Comment: I'm trying to compare the category type which is a string to a textbox input which is in this case E&D

Comment: Like @stuartd said, or, HtmlEncode the literal "E&D" prior to comparison.

Comment: @stuartd Thank you! That worked.

Answer (score 1):

> HttpUtility.HtmlDecode Method (String)

**Converts a string that has been HTML-encoded for HTTP transmission into a decoded string.**

refer- [msdn link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7c5fyk1k(v=vs.110).aspx) 
As you are using html string getting from textbox you need to decode that string first.

Below code will work in your case-

```
            string CategoryType = "E&amp;D";
            if (HttpUtility.HtmlDecode(CategoryType).ToUpper() == "E&D")
            {

            }
```